# How to register a default Observer for every Model instance with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

## Laravel 5.1

I'm trying to register a single model observer for every Model that extends my AbstractModel (who are extending Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model).

The problem is my GenericModelObserver can't listen to events fired by Models inheriting AbstractModel.

Let me show what I did so far.

A Service Provider was created and put on the last position of the providers array inside config/app.php

```
<?php

// app/Providers/ObserverServiceProvider.php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Models\Quotation;
use App\Models\AbstractModel;
use App\Observers\QuotationObserver;
use App\Observers\GenericModelObserver;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ObserverServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    public function boot()
    {
        AbstractModel::observe(GenericModelObserver::class);
        Quotation::observe(QuotationObserver::class);
    }

    public function register()
    {

    }
}
```

Then I have my plain simple GenericModelObserver

```
<?php

// app/Observers/GenericModelObserver.php

namespace App\Observers;

use App\Models\AbstractModel;

class GenericModelObserver
{
    public function saving(AbstractModel $model)
    {
        return $model->valid();
    }
}
```

The Abstract Model

```
<?php

// app/Models/AbstractModel.php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class AbstractModel extends Model
{
    // ...
}
```

My Quotation Model

```
<?php

// app/Models/Quotation.php

namespace App\Models;

class Quotation extends AbstractModel
{
    // ...
}
```

When Quotation is saved, the GenericModelObserver can't listen to the saving event or any other event.

The same applies for other Models that don't have a specific Model Observer.

Is this the right strategy? I would not like to bind a observer to every model through the boot method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simply extend a parent class say `BaseObserver`

I have something similar in my caching system

```
<?php namespace App\Observers;
class BaseObserver {
    public function saving($model)
    {
        //do your thing here that apply to all observers, like caching
    }
}
```

Then in your `Observers`

```
<?php namespace App\Observers;
class Quotation extends BaseObserver{
   //you can override any of the methods if you wish
}
```

Comment: My problem is not exactly how to override the BaseObserver. I need to attach the BaseObserver once and make it listen to every instance extending the AbstractModel. I tried but could not link your answer to what I need, could you enlighten me? Thank you for you work.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of extending model - write your own trait which will work as observer.
Below I wrote some basic trait:

```
<?php

namespace App\YourPackage\Traits;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

trait Observable
{
    public static function bootObservable()
    {
        static::updating(function (Model $model) {
            dd('updating');
        });
    }
}
```

and use it by typing `use Observable;` in your model class.

Also for your learning take a note how traits is booting: You have to put `boot[TraitClassName]` method into trait, to boot it properly.
Never write `boot` method inside your trait, it's dangerous!

Comment: With this approach the specific boot method is not triggered. Ex you want a generic trait for all models then in each model you want something different.

Comment: Pitfall: `static::updating` etc. can only exist once per model. This can lead to collisions with multiple traits (i.e. `Observable`, `Auditable`, etc.). Better to create a distinct observer class and use `public function initializeObservable() { $this->registerObserver(Observer::class); }` instead.

Comment: Pitfall pitfall: use `public static function bootObservable() { self::observe(Observer::class); }` instead. The previous code would register duplicate observers to a single model.

Answer (score 5):

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Observers\TeamObserver;

class Team extends Model
{
    /**
     * The "booting" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        self::observe(TeamObserver::class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Update the `boot` method in your `AppServiceProvider` to the following:

```
public function boot()
{
    # Register all model observers
    $filesInFolder = \File::files(app_path('/Observers'));

    foreach($filesInFolder as $path) {
        $observerClassName = pathinfo($path)['filename'];
        $className = str_replace('Observer', '', $observerClassName);
        $observerClassName = 'App\\Observers\\' . $observerClassName;
        $className = 'App\\' . $className;
        $className::observe($observerClassName);
    }
}
```

Models should follow this format:

`App\User`

Observers should follow this format:

`App\Observers\UserObserver`

When models are in the 'models' folder:
Swap this `$className = 'App\\' . $className;` for this `$className = 'App\\Models\\' . $className;`

Answer (score 0):

In your parent model you can do something like that

```
/**
 * If true will attach the observers of the parent class
 * @var bool
 */
protected $shouldAttachParentObservers = true;

public static function boot()
{
    $instance = new static;
    $instance->attachParentObservers();

    parent::boot();
}


public function attachParentObservers() {
    $parentClass = get_parent_class($this);
    if(!empty($parentClass) && $this->shouldAttachParentObservers) {
        $eventObservers = [];
        foreach ($this->getObservableEvents() as $event) {
            $eventObservers[$event] = ($this::$dispatcher->getListeners("eloquent.{$event}: {$parentClass}"));
            foreach ($eventObservers[$event] as $observer) {
                $eventName = "eloquent.{$event}: {$this::getClassName()}";
                $this::$dispatcher->listen($eventName, $observer);
            }
        }
    }
}
/**
 * You may use different way to find the class name
 */
public static function getClassName() {
    return static::class;
}
```